# Why is a callback flag being cleared and/or corrupted without apparent cause?

Tags: c++, callback, interrupt

I am writing an SD card SPI driver for a processor. I know the SPI driver is good because I also use it for an LCD and, until now, have been sending commands merrily to the card. I am having trouble with one specific transaction, which is no different to any other in any way I can see.

Upon writing data out on the SPI bus, I wait for interrupt callbacks to say that the receive and transmit are complete. There are two callbacks, which set the following boolean flags in a `struct` to true:

`m_transaction_status.sdts_rx_complete`

`m_transaction_status.sdts_tx_complete`

In normal program flow, I wait for these flags to be set before carrying on:

```
while ((m_transaction_status.sdts_rx_complete == false) //
        || (m_transaction_status.sdts_tx_complete == false))
{
    // Check whether we've had an error.
    if (m_transaction_status.sdts_error == true)
    {
        LOG_ERROR(SD::MODULE,
                "transfer_data: Transaction error.");
        transfer_status = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

For the problem transaction, I set a breakpoint in the callback and can see that both flags are being set, yet when I return to the normal flow, the variables are suddenly unavailable and seemingly `false` since I'm then forever stuck in the loop. This loop is used for every other transaction without issue.

Is there any reason that I could investigate as to why these variables are being set but then (apparently) being cleared or deallocated or something else untoward?

EDIT:

The interrupt is indeed that of a micro (Renesas RL78 to be precise).

The struct declaration is:

```
/**
 * The state of an SD SPI transaction.
 */
struct SDTransactionStatus
{
    /** Transaction error flag. */
    bool sdts_error;
    /** Transmission completion flag. */
    bool sdts_tx_complete;
    /** Reception completion flag. */
    bool sdts_rx_complete;
};
```

The `struct` is implemented as a private member of my `SD` class. The flags are set via a simple setter function in the callback.

Comment: Please confirm that your "interrupt callback" actually is an Interrupt Service Routine (on a microcontroller?). Also, please show both the declaration of `m_transaction_status` and the declaration of its type (the `struct`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your particular microcontroller nor the C++ compiler you have to use with it, but this shouldn't change anything about what I'm going to say.

I believe the problem is, in your loop you never change the value of your flags, you just read them, so the compiler is free to optimize things away and read your variables just once outside the loop (ie. cache them) because it doesn't know they can change. Something along the lines of:

```
const bool complete = !m_transaction_status.sdts_rx_complete
                   || !m_transaction_status.sdts_tx_complete;
const bool error = m_transaction_status.sdts_error;
while (complete) {
  if (error) {
    //...
  }
}
```

You see why this can't give good results. The fix is to tell the compiler that your variables *can* change "behind its back", and that it actually needs to re-read them *every time you access them in your code*.

Since you're not multithreading or anything, you can do it simply by adding a `volatile` qualifier to your variables in your declaration of your `struct`:

```
struct SDTransactionStatus
{
    volatile bool sdts_error;
    volatile bool sdts_tx_complete;
    volatile bool sdts_rx_complete;
};
```

Now, why you didn't stumble on this problem earlier is kind of a mystery, but you have to keep in mind that "*the compiler is free to optimize*" doesn't mean it always *has to*. As a wild guess I'd say that the other places you used that loop didn't lend themselves to such optimization, while the place where you have the problem does.

Of course I could be wrong about the whole thing but with so little information it's hard to tell, and anyway this optimization/volatile issue still exists in your code even if it's not the cause of your current problem so you still have to fix it because even if your current problem is unrelated, what I described could happen any time.

**Edit:** Oh, and you should probably review your *whole* code base to ensure this doesn't happen somewhere else too.

Comment: Thank you for such a good answer. I'll try the fix and let you know if I get the same problem. Thinking about it, the *only* difference I can think of with the "problem transaction" and others is that it's right off the back of two previous transactions. This sort of falls in line with your "lending itself to" optimisation idea.

Comment: Unfortunately this fix didn't work. For a bit more information, I set a breakpoint on the preceding transaction and saw that when I returned from the interrupt and into the `while` loop, my variable watch window correctly showed the values of all the `m_transaction_status` flags. On the problem transaction though, they are all *unavailable*. I will try to lump all the transactions together (since they form a single data packet), but save for that working, do you have any further ideas?

Comment: And a little bit of further information: On the first two transactions, the watch window says it's looking for the `m_transaction_status` `struct` at address `0xFB686`. In the final transaction, it's looking in `0x100215`. I do not do anything with the `SD` object in-between each transaction (they literally follow each other in code).

Comment: @EdKing: You should look at the assembly output to see what really happens. I know that normally one should think about a bug in his own code rather than in the compiler, but from my (small) experience on µC I found that their compilers are rather poor quality and sometimes generate weird/incorrect assembly even though the C/C++ code is perfectly correct, so be prepared for the worst. Maybe just reordering/refactoring your code would do the trick? (I remember one instance where I **had** to use `if/else` because the ternary operator `?:` would yield incorrect assembly... frightening! o_O)

Comment: I changed the code to use just one transaction at this point and the flags are now correct by the time I get back to the `while` loop. I didn't go so far as to look at the assembly but know now that I might need to go down this route in the future. This is quite an odd bug, but nonetheless I've found a workaround for now. Thanks.